# In OWL 1; are min 1 Thing and some Thing equivalent?

Tags: owl, ontology

In OWL 1; What is the difference between:

```
Parent subclassOf hasChildren min 1 Thing
```

and

```
Parent subclassOf hasChildren some Thing
```

Are they equivalent as both of them assert that each `Parent` instance must has at least one value from any class through `hasChildren`? as we don't specify a particular range for the `someValuesFrom` restriction?

Comment: You can't really say the first in OWL1;  OWL1 doesn't have qualified cardinality restrictions.  In OWL2 you can say it, though.  At any rate, this question might also be answered by [owl:someValuesFrom vs. owl:minCardinalilty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24629308/1281433).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In OWL 1; What is the difference between:
>
> > Parent subclassOf hasChildren min 1 Thing
>
> and
>
> > Parent subclassOf hasChildren some Thing

OWL1 doesn't have qualified cardinality restrictions.  You can't say

- property min n Class

in OWL1.  You can use unqualified cardinality restrictions (1), and qualified existential restrictions, like:

1. property min n
2. property some Class

In OWL 2, where you do have qualified cardinality restrictions, you have the ability to write

- property min n Class

and you're absolutely right that the following are equivalent:

- property min 1 Class
- property some Class

and as a special case, the following are equivalent:

- property min 1 owl:Thing
- property some owl:Thing

Comment: is saying A subclassOf min 1 in OWL1 (unqualified cardinality restriction) equivalent to saying A subclassOf min 1 Thing in OWL2?

Answer (score 1):

The `someValuesFrom`in OWL is equivalent to the existential quantifier in **predicate logic**:

> In predicate logic, an existential quantification is a type of quantifier, a logical constant which is interpreted as "there exists," "there is at least one," or "for some." It expresses that a propositional function can be satisfied by at least one member of a domain of discourse. In other terms, it is the predication of a property or relation to at least one member of the domain. It asserts that a predicate within the scope of an existential quantifier is true of at least one value of a predicate variable.

Keeping this in mind, please refer to the definition of **Restirction**:

> OWL Lite allows restrictions to be placed on how properties can be used by instances of a class.

And the definition of **Cardinality**:

> OWL (and OWL Lite) cardinality restrictions are referred to as local restrictions, since they are stated on properties with respect to a particular class. That is, the restrictions constrain the cardinality of that property on instances of that class.

In OWL, `someValuesFrom` has been defined as:

> The restriction someValuesFrom is stated on a property with respect to a class. A particular class may have a restriction on a property that at least one value for that property is of a certain **type**.

And `minCardinality` has been defined as:

> If a minCardinality of 1 is stated on a property with respect to a class, then **any instance** of that class will be **related** to at least one individual by that property.

So, although logically they are the same, they represent different ideas.

Comment: **"So, although logically they might seem the same, they represent different ideas."** Logically they *are* the same.

Comment: **"So, although logically they might seem the same, they represent different ideas."** Logically they *are* the same (in the example from the question).  Saying that "Parent subClassOf hasChildren min 1 Thing" means that every instance of Parent is related to at least one Thing by the hasChildren property.  Saying that "Parent subClassOf hasChildren some Thing" means that every instance of Parent is related to at least on Thing by the hasChildren property.  Of course, in OWL1, you can't say "hasChildren min 1 Thing";  you can only say "hasChildren min 1".  However, since every individual is...

Comment: ...an instance of Thing, saying (in OWL1) "hasChildren min 1" is the same as saying (in OWL2) "hasChildren min 1 Thing".